# Magento2: GA e-commerce module

Tags: magento2

I added the GA tracking code on my website. I see users in real time. Then I enable the e-commerce module. I would like to see all the purchases in GA in our store.
Unfortunately, this data is not transferred to GA. How can I do this?

[image]

GA:
[image]

Comment: are you using magento built-in GA features?

Comment: yes, I use the  GA built-in magento functions.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsFhE.png

Comment: well the functionality is pretty limited for built-in google tag manager of magento. You can use this free module and it is pretty good
https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html

Comment: Ok, I check this. You can answear  this topic maybe any be looking for that, I'll give you vota.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in functionality of google tag manager in Magento 2 is pretty limited. Although you can develop a separate module for it and enhance the functionality, I advise you to use Weltpixle google tag manager free module. It has lots of beneficial features 
https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html